# Does Firebase Messaging Service shut down when application crashes?

Tags: android, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have used a simple sample of **FirebaseMessagingService** in my project. In some cases as I have complex situation the application may crashes. I can not receive anymore messages from FCM after crash.

My exact question is if the FCM service shuts down when the main application crashes? if YES how should I force it restart again (when the app is no more available) programmatically? Does google services restarts the FCM automatically in background?

Comment: You can restart it through the npm console window

Comment: Can you explain which type of crash you are talking about.? Because in my samsung device, FCM works fine even after crash (Unhandeled Exception)

Comment: In the case of this question I have nullPointer exception on an instance of MediaRecorder. I have samsung N8 and it stops receiving anymore notifications after crash. Do you know if FCM remains alive even if the main app crashes? @NaitikSoni